# how to count and change value in dataframe by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count the number of times a value False appears in my dataframe and get the number of how many times False appears in a row.

So here is how my table should look initially:

| A | B | C | D | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | True | False | 0 |
| Second | row | False | True | 0 |
| Third | row | True | True | 0 |
| Fourth | row | False | False | 0 |

This is how it should look:

| A | B | C | D | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | True | False | 1 |
| Second | row | False | True | 1 |
| Third | row | True | True | 0 |
| Fourth | row | False | False | 2 |

This is my code, I have tried to count for at least one column to begin with something, but it does not change the value in count column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['One', None, 'One', None], 'B': [None, 'Two', None, 'Two'], 'C': [True, False, True, False],
        'D': [False, True, True, False], 'count': [0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['C'] is False:
                row['count'] += 1
print(df.head(4))
```

Comment: Is `2` due to having False in Second and then Fourth? or because you have it both in C and D?

Comment: Because it is in both C and D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to count the `False` (boolean) values per row?

You can subset the boolean columns with [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), then invert the boolean value with `~` (so that `False` becomes `True` and is equivalent to `1`), then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) per row:

```
df['count'] = (~df.select_dtypes('boolean')).sum(axis=1)
```

output:

```
      A     B      C      D  count
0   One  None   True  False      1
1  None   Two  False   True      1
2   One  None   True   True      0
3  None   Two  False  False      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Select columns 'C' and 'D', flip/invert the booleans (`~`) and then sum across both columns:

```
df['count'] = (~df[['C', 'D']]).sum(axis='columns')
```

Comment: I must admit, the code by @mozway is a little bit more elegant because it selects the relevant columns based on their dtypes (data types), while I do this manually.